# view that outputs user input on a different url

Tags: django, django-views

i created a view + form that creates two widgets + a button for a  user. One to select a choice and another to type something in. Now i want to redirect the user after the clicking the button to another webpage displaying his input. (Generally i want to know how to access the userinput and further use it).

This is my form:

```
class Eingabefeld(forms.Form):
    eingabefeld = forms.CharField(label="Flight Number",max_length=20)
    a = Auswahlmoeglichkeiten.objects.all()
    flughafenname = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Target Airport",queryset=a,empty_label="-------")
    source = forms.CharField(       
    max_length=50,             
    widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
    required=False
)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def get_eingabe(request):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if request.method =="POST":
        eingabe = Eingabefeld(request.POST)
        log.warn(eingabe)
        if eingabe.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("answerrequest")
    else:
        eingabe = Eingabefeld()
    return render(request, "app_one/labels.html", {"eingabe": eingabe})

def answerrequestseite(request):
    return render(request, "app_one/answerrequest.html")
```

and this is my html ( the included html in this one is just for layout):

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include "app_one/bootstrap_layout2.html" with form=eingabe %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Let's Go!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So basically when opening my webpage "get_eingabe" gets called, and the template gets rendered, now when clicking the button the input is validated and after successfull validation a different URL is opened which will trigger the method "answerrequestseite". Now how do i pass the userinput (eingabefeld and flughafenname) into the other method which will render the template for the second URL?

I read alot about using "request.GET" but i am not quite sure where exactly to place it and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `if eingabe.is_valid():` create some variable containing the values you want.
then in you redirect you need to pass those values as get argument like:
your_url/?id=123

Then you can retrieve your variable in your views.py via
    request.GET.get('id')

But in your case, you don't want to pass simple id, you want to pass user_input.
One way will be to sanitize this input to make it url compatible.

Otherwise the more flexible solution is to store the values in the session.

Session (via cookie)

```
# views.py
# Set the session variable
request.session['you_variable_name_here'] = 'the value'

# Retrieve the session variable
var = request.session.get['you_variable_name_here']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

For your exemple in the first view:

```
if eingabe.is_valid():
    eingabefeld = eingabe.cleaned_data.get('eingabefeld')
    flughafenname = eingabe.cleaned_data.get('flughafenname')
    request.session['eingabefeld'] = eingabefeld
    request.session['flughafenname'] = flughafenname.pk
    return HttpResponseRedirect("answerrequest")
```

In the second view:

```
def answerrequestseite(request):
    eingabefeld = request.session.get('eingabefeld')
    flughafenname_pk = request.session.get('flughafenname')
    flughafenname = YourFlughafennameModel.objects.get(pk=flughafenname_pk)
    return render(request, "app_one/answerrequest.html",{'eingabefeld':eingabefeld,'flughafenname':flughafenname})
```

Comment: ok first and foremost, thanks for the answer, i tried to implement your code, with setting the session variable in the first view like so: request.session['eingabefeld'] = eingabefeld. I am using bootstrap4 for my html templates. When running the code i got the error : "Object of type 'Auswahlmoeglichkeiten' is not JSON serializable".

Comment: i think this has something that flughafenname is a ModelChoiceField with a QuerySet, so i tried it only for eingabefeld and got a different error, a TypeError: "'method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: sorry, replace [] by () in the second view

Comment: yes this removed the error for eingabefeld, i now can render the first input, yet for flughafenname i get the above mentioned error, is it because of the value of the ModelChoiceField being a QuerySet?

Comment: I just realise I forget to give you the two line after form valid haha. What do you get when you print flughafenname inside the view?

Comment: So print after flughafenname = eingabe.cleaned_data.get('flughafenname') will give me my selected Choice, i know now that the error occurs at "request.session['flughafenname'] = flughafenname" by commenting out different lines of code

Comment: What if you only save the id in the session `request.session['flughafenname']=flughafenname.id` and in the second view query the dayabase with tha id. `Flughafenname.objects.get(pk=flughafenname)`

Comment: i tried it with going for the id and it worked, thanks alot for your help!